# Android - Storing files in computer

Tags: android

I'm developing an android application which records sounds ..

I want to save the recorded sound file directly in my computer rather than storing in the sdcard of the emulator ?
How can I do this?

Comment: If you don't want to store it on the phone, you can transfer it over the network to a server. There is a space vs data usage tradeoff here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Web-Service for such operation. The Web-Service can be develop in Servlet,PHP or using .net